# mongoosJS updating a nested date value

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm not getting an updated value when trying to set a date

The Schema looks like this

```
const CouponSchema = new Schema({
    coupon: {
        type: String
        ,required: true
    }
    ,type: {
        type: String
        ,required: true
    }
    ,user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
        ,required: true
    }
    ,date: {
        issued: {
            type: Date
            ,default: Date.now
        }
        ,redeemed: {
            type: Date
            ,default: null
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried this

```
module.exports.redeem = function( id, callback ) {
    Coupon.findByIdAndUpdate( id, {
        $set: {
            "date.redeemed": Date.now
        }
    }, callback);
}
```

And this

```
module.exports.redeem = function( id, callback ) {
    Coupon.findByIdAndUpdate( id, {
        $set: {
            "date": {
                "redeemed": Date.now
            }
        }
    }, callback);
}
```

I get no errors, but the dates never get populated. Suggestions?

Comment: insted of `Date.now()`  have you tried to pass `new Date()`  ?

Comment: I have not but I will.

Comment: Well, I took not of your (), and tried that first. and it seemed to work. Although my $set killed the rest of the "date" structure, so Im trying to fix that and have broken things again. suffice it to say - I think you gae me my answer - thank you. now onto the next issue

Answer (score 0):

so, You are using `Date.now()` that returns numbered value `timestamp`
 like below:

```
> Date.now()
1517473075986
```

and you are passing this to a `Date` type field, that only takes Date Objects,
following command returns Date Object. which can be accepted by Date type fields.

```
> new Date()
2018-02-01T08:19:49.360Z
```

example:

```
{
  issued: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  },
  redeemed: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  }
}
```

So, insted of `Date.now()` you can pass `new Date()` , that should work. ;)